why @can laravel 10 not working for permission?
Excuse me, I'm a junior developer and I'm still learning about the Laravel gates concept. I have a table structure like this.
I have two admin users. One real admin and one normal admin.
Real admin has access to all options. But the normal admin only has access to the dashboard.
@can('dashboard')
<a>dashboard</a>
@endcan

@can('users')
<a>users</a>
@endcan

A normal admin should only see the dashboard, but he can see everything.
AuthServiceProvider.php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use App\Models\Permission;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The model to policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array<class-string, class-string>
     */
    protected $policies = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::before(function($user) {
            if($user->isAdmin()) return true;
        });

        foreach (Permission::all() as $permission) {
            Gate::define($permission->name , function($user) use ($permission){
                return $user->hasPermission($permission);
            });
        }
    }

}

User.php
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->level == 'admin' ? true : false;
}

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}

public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
}

public function hasRole($roles)
{
    return !! $roles->intersect($this->roles)->all() ;
}

public function hasPermission($permission)
{
    return $this->permissions->contains('name' , $permission->name) || $this->hasRole($permission->roles);
}

tables
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('label')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('permission_user' , function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('permission_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->primary(['permission_id', 'user_id']);
    });
}

public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('label')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('role_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);
    });

    Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('permission_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('role_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
    });
}

Any idea what it's trying to get at?

Any idea what it's trying to get at?
